# How to Add Update Delete a Duplicate Key Value Pair List

Tags: c#, linq

I need to have a generic Method in order to Add Update Delete from a Duplicate Key Value Pair list

My Duplicate Key Value pair looks like this

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> dupesStudentIdsList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1234_456X", 1));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1234_456X", 2));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1234_456X", 3));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1234_456X", 4));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1234_456X", 5));
        //new set of duplicate ids with increasing rowNumber 
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("9999_999A", 1));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("9999_999A", 2));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("9999_999A", 4));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("9999_999A", 5));
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("9999_999A", 6));
```

What i need now 
 When i pass the Key it should remove all the rows for that key.

```
 private void RemoveDupesbyKey(string DupeKey) //passing "1234_456X"
 {
 }
```

//Expected Result when key is passed as "1234_456X"

```
("9999_999A", 1));
("9999_999A", 2));
("9999_999A", 4));
("9999_999A", 5));
("9999_999A", 6));
```

Now I want to Remove only one Record by passing both Key and Value ("9999_999A", 6)

```
private void RemoveByPassingKeyandValue(string key , int Value) // this is passed
{
}
```

//Expected Result

```
("9999_999A", 1));
("9999_999A", 2));
("9999_999A", 4));
("9999_999A", 5));  // last row is removed.
```

//Update only Value passing the key and value

```
  private void updateValueOnly(string key , int Value) // Only Value update for the Key
    {
    }
```

//Expected Result

```
("9999_999A", 1));
("9999_999A", 2));
("9999_999A", 4));
("9999_999A", 999999));  //only value is updated for that key and value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i managed. If there is a better approach i would be thankful.

```
   private void RemoveDupesbyKey(string DupeKey) //passing "1234_456X"
{
    dupesStudentIdsList.RemoveAll(x => x.Key.Equals(Dupekey));
}

private void RemoveByPassingKeyandValue(string key, int Value) // this is passed
{
    dupesStudentIdsList.Remove(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(key, Value));
}
```

Since KeyValuePair  is Immutable. We need to remove it and add it.

```
private void UpdateValueOnly(string key, int Value) // this is passed
{

  if (dupesStudentIdList.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(key) && x.Value.Equals(Value).Any()))//check if it matches 
    {
        //remove
        dupesStudentIdsList.Remove(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(key, Value));
        // add 
        dupesStudentIdsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(key, Value));
    }

}
```